# 8 gb MS SQL AWE

Tags: sql-server

Добрый день, интересует информация:

`Windows Server 2003 R2 Standart x32` добавляю оперативу до 8 гб, должен ли `Windows` видеть (видеть, а не использовать) их? В свойствах системы показывает только 4, в биосе все 8. Могу ли я задействовать в `MSSQL AWE` мои лишние 4гб в `x32` системе?

Comment: что больше никто по практике не сталкивался?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый короткий ответ - нет, проверено на практике.

Comment: видать ты один сталкивался с этим вопросом, сам решения не нашел... видать ты прав( Спасибо.